# Grouping with geojson in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have an mongodb collection that contains document in form of

```
{ "name":"test","city":"c1","geom":{"type": "Point","coordinates":[66,33]} }
{ "name":"test","city":"c1","geom":{"type": "Point","coordinates":[77,22]} }
```

now i want to group geometries by city name and create a POLYGON feature i cant figure out how can i achieve this and weather mongodb support this or not. If i try to craete an aggregate on geom it throws `"The field 'geom' must be an accumulator object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [accumulator operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulators-group).

Restrictions:

- Closed [LineStrings](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#linestring) have at least **four** coordinate pairs and specify the same position *as the first and last coordinates*.
- For Polygons with a single ring, the ring cannot self-intersect.

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        city: "$city",
        name: "$name"
      },
      coordinates: {
        $push: "$geom.coordinates"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      city: "$_id.city",
      name: "$_id.name",
      type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: [
        "$coordinates"
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h1u_HJjMRsV) | [Valid Polygon](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W1c3lcTJHQF)